# How to count the line in a text file in a specific path and assign that count to a variable in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I have a text file in a specific path.
Now i want to count the number of lines in a text file and store that value to a variable, so that i can use that variable value in my for loop.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`find` has the `/c` parameter to count it's findings. Another paramteter `/v` to look for lines, that doesn't contain the search string. As there is no really empty line in a file (it does contain at least a linefeed), you can search for all lines containing nothing and count the findings:

```
find /c /v "" file.txt
```

You can then parse the output to get the number of lines. But `find` does output the number only when not parsing a file, but parsing from STDIN, so let's use that:

```
<file.txt find /c /v ""
```

To get the output to a variable, use a `for` loop:

```
for /f %%i in ('^<file.txt find /c /v ""') do set count=%%i
```

(if you use it on command line, use `%i` instead of `%%i`)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried it but its not working. Basically i have a text file in path C:\Project\Wind\File.txt.  Now i want to count the number of lines in this text file. So from the answer provided by you where to mention the path of the file. i am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: how about `<"C:\Project\Wind\File.txt" find /c /v ""`?

Comment: Thanks its working. but i am trying to assign the value to a variable but its not working. i tried this command: for /f%%i in ('^<"C:\Project\Wind\file.txt" find /c /v ""') do set /A b=%%i. its giving an error. i want to get the output in a variable. its giving me an error "%%i was unexpected at this time." can you please help me with this.

Comment: read the last sentence again: `(if you use it on command line, use %i instead of %%i)`